Understanding the proof of a simplfied version of the Aubin-Lions lemma
I am following the textbook The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations by Robinson, Rodrigo, and Sadowski. I am confused on some parts of their proof for a simplified version of the Aubin-Lions Lemma. Most of the questions I have are general functional analysis questions and not related to the Navier-Stokes equations.
To establish notation they denote the following:

$H$ is the set of $L^2$ functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^3$ (the 3-torus) to $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are divergence free
$V := H \cap (H^1)^3$ where $(H^1)^3$ is the function space $H^1 \times H^1 \times H^1$ (either on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^3$) and where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$. In other words, $V$ is the set of all divergence free vector fields whose components are all in $H^1$
$V^*$ is the dual of $V$
$A$ is the Stokes operator whose action is defined as $Au = \mathbb{P}\Delta u$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the Leray projector and $\Delta$ is the Laplacian
$\mathcal{N}$ is the set of eigenfunctions of the Stokes operator, which form a basis for $H(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is equal to $\mathbb{T}^3$ or a smooth bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$

The refer to the following lemma in their proof. Here $X$ is a Banach space:

Lemma 1.31 Suppose that $u, g \in L^1(0, T; X)$. Then the following are equivalent

$u$ has weak time derivative $g$;
there exists $\xi \in X$ such that $$u(t) = \xi + \int_0^t g(s) ds \quad \textrm{for almost every } t \in [0,T];$$
for every $f \in X^*$ $$\frac{d}{dt} \langle f, u \rangle = \langle f, g \rangle,$$ where the time derivative is taken in the weak sense.

In particular, if (1)-(3) hold then $u$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function from $[0,T]$ into $X$.

The simplified version of the lemma says:

Aubin-Lions Lemma; simple version Let $\Omega$ be the torus $\mathbb{T}^3$ or a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If the sequence $(u_n)$ is uniformly bounded in $L^q(0, T; V)$, $q > 1$, and the partial derivatives $\partial_t u _n$ are uniformly bounded in $L^p(0, T; V^*)$, $p > 1$, then there exist $u \in L^q(0, T; H)$ and a subsequence of $(u_n)$ that converges strongly to $u$ in $L^q(0, T; H)$.

Their proof is as follows. I will put my questions in bold.

We will first obtain bounds on finite-dimensional projections of the sequence $(u_n)$. To this end let us consider $\langle u_n, a_j\rangle$, where $a_j \in \mathcal{N}$ is an eigenfunction of the Stokes operator corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$. From Lemma 1.31 we can deduce that $\langle u_n, a_j \rangle$ is absolutely continuous with $\frac{d}{dt}\langle u_n, a_j \rangle = \langle \partial_t u_n, a_j \rangle$ almost everywhere on $[0, T]$ so $$\langle u_n(s), a_j \rangle = \langle u_n(s^*), a_j \rangle + \int_{s^*}^s \langle \partial_t u_n, a_j \rangle$$ for almost every $s \in [0, T]$.


How does absolute continuity of $\langle u_n, a_j \rangle$ follow from Lemma 1.31 above?


Using an idea from Lemma 10.4 in Renardy & Rogers (2004), there exists a time $s^* \in [0,T]$ such that $$\langle u_n(s^*), a_j \rangle = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \langle u_n, a_j \rangle$$ and we can estimate $\langle u_n(s), a_j \rangle$ as follows: $$\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} | \langle u_n(s), a_j\rangle| \leq |\langle u_n(s^*), a_j \rangle| + \Big|\int_{s^*}^s \langle \partial_t u_n, a_j \rangle \Big| \\ \leq \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \|u_n\|_{L^2}\|a_j\|_{L^2} + \int_0^T \|\partial_t u_n\|_{V^*} \|a_j\|_V\\ \leq \frac{1}{T} \|u_n\|_{L^q(0, T; H)} T^{1-1/q} + \|\partial_t u_n\|_{L^p(0, T; V^*)} T^{1-1/p}\lambda_j^{1/2} \\ \leq C_1 + C_2 \lambda_j^{1/2}.$$ (We used Hölder's inequality and the equality $\|a_j\|_V^2 = \|\nabla a_j \|^2 = \lambda_j$.) Therefore if we define $$P_ku_n = \sum_{j=1}^k \langle u_n, a_j \rangle a_j$$ then $P_ku_n \in C([0, T]; H)$ and $$\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T} \|P_ku_n(s)\|_{L^2} \leq \sum_{j=1}^k (C_1 + C_2 \lambda_j^{1/2}) \leq k(C_1 + C_2\lambda_k^{1/2}) \tag{4.20}$$ because $(\lambda_j)$ is an increasing sequence.


Should the right-hand side of the first inequality also contain a supremum? If not, how did they get rid of it?
How does this show that $P_ku_n \in C([0, T]; H)$?


We claim that for each fixed $k$ the sequence $(P_ku_n)$ has a subsequence that converges in $C([0,T]; P_kH)$. So let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. From (4.20) we know that the sequence $(P_ku_n)$ is uniformly bounded with values in a finite-dimensional space $P_kH$. Hence there is a compact set $K \subset P_kH$ such that $P_ku_n: [0,T] \rightarrow K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$


How does uniform boundedness imply the existence of the compact set $K$?


Moreover, the sequence $(P_ku_n)$ is equicontinuous; to prove this we use the fact that $P_kH$ is finite dimensional, and so the norms $\|\cdot\|_L^2\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_{V^*}$ are equivalent on $P_kH$. We can therefore prove the equicontinuity of $(P_ku_n)$ as follows: $$\|P_ku_n(t_2) - P_ku_n(t_1)\|_{L^2} = \Big\|\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \partial_t P_ku_n(s) ds\Big\|_{L^2} \\ \leq \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \|\partial_t P_k u_n(s)\|_{L^2} ds \\ \leq c_k \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \|\partial_t P_ku_n(s)\|_{V^*} ds \\ \leq c_k \Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \|\partial_t P_ku_n(s)\|_{V^*}^p ds \Big)^{1/p} \Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2} ds \Big)^{1-1/p} \\ \leq \tilde{c}_k|t_2 - t_1|^{1-1/p}.$$ An application of the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem now provides a convergent subsequence in $C([0,T]; P_kH)$ as claimed.


I am a bit confused on how this shows equicontinuity. Wouldn't we have to vary $k$ and not $t$?

I am able to understand the rest of the proof so I have omitted it.
